# Where should I validate business rules involving 2 or more entities in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

one of my business rules is to check the state of an entity when updating another different, related entity. Where and how should I implement this validation? I know it should be done at the Model, but have not found examples for LINQ-to-SQL and EF. Thank you.

Comment: Check this [Blog post by Scott Gu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/10/class-level-model-validation-with-ef-code-first-and-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always, the answer is "it depends".

In my solution, my UI talks to my service layer.  My service layer has access to my entities (and their entity-specific logic) and my repository.  In the cases where I have logic that operates against multiple entities, I keep it in the service layer.  I have to be careful though about leaning too much towards an anemic model where my entities are merely data bags.